# Add draggable element to div dynamically by jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to add `row (div)` and then add `button` to `row` with drag and drop in **jQuery UI** like this: ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/4u8dcL5p/3/))

**html**

```
<div class="rowDashboard">Row</div>
<div class="buttonDashboard">Button</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**script**

```
var rowIndex = 0;
var buttonIndex = 0;

$(init);

function init() {
    $('.rowDashboard').draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: addNewRow,       
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $('#content').droppable({      
        accept: ".rowDashboard",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            ui.helper.attr('style', '');
            $(ui.helper).addClass('rowDraggable');
            ui.helper.clone().appendTo('#content');
        },
    });

    //------ sortable rows --------------
    $("#content").sortable({
        cancel: ".fixed"
    });
    $("#content").disableSelection();
    // ----------------------------------

    //------- buttonDraggable -----------
    $('.buttonDashboard').draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: addNewButton,
    });
    // ----------------------------------

    $('.rowDraggable').droppable({       
        accept: ".buttonDashboard",      
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            ui.helper.attr('style', '');
            $(ui.helper).addClass('buttonDraggable');
            ui.helper.clone().appendTo($(this));
        },
    });
}

function addNewButton() {
    buttonIndex++;
    return '<input type=\'button\' value=\'button ' + buttonIndex + ' \'>   </input>';
}

function addNewRow() {
    rowIndex++;
    return '<div> Row ' + rowIndex + '  </div>';
}
```

But I don't know why `button` will not be added to `row`.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this issue.

Comment: You can check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4u8dcL5p/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. I'm applying the `droppable` before `row` elements are created.

I edited this portion ([Solution JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/54yn469v/)):

```
$('#content').droppable({      
        accept: ".rowDashboard",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            ui.helper.attr('style', '');
            $(ui.helper).addClass('rowDraggable');
            ui.helper.clone().appendTo('#content');
        },
    });
```

to:

```
$('#content').droppable({
    accept: ".rowDashboard",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        ui.helper.attr('style', '');
        $(ui.helper).addClass('rowDraggable');
        $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
        $item.appendTo('#content');
        enableDroppable($item); // Dynamically enable droppable property of new row.
    },
});

// this method enables droppable property item
function enableDroppable($item) {
    $item.droppable({
        accept: ".buttonDashboard",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            ui.helper.attr('style', '');
            $(ui.helper).addClass('buttonDraggable');
            ui.helper.clone().appendTo($(this));
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify this code in the line 14:

```
$('#content').droppable({      
    accept: ".rowDashboard, .buttonDashboard",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        ui.helper.attr('style', '');
        if(ui.draggable.hasClass('rowDashboard')) {
             $(ui.helper).addClass('rowDraggable');
        } else { 
             $(ui.helper).addClass('buttonDraggable');
        } 

        $(ui.helper).addClass('rowDraggable');
        ui.helper.clone().appendTo('#content');
    },
});
```

Comment: With this change `button` can be added to `content`. It should only be added to `row`.